# Passing JS variable to php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables

Hope someone could help me. I'm new to web programming and I already spent hours to find the solution. I have to add php arrays (here $pu and $mArray) with JS. These arrays are multi-dimentional. I'd like to get the variable 'i' instead of the index '1' of the both arrays. I tried a lot without success. Help.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    chart.addSeries({
    name: '<?php echo $pu['1']; ?>',
    data: [<?php echo join($mArray['1'], ', '); ?>]
});
```

Comment: You can't, PHP is executed on the server long before the `i` even exists.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that PHP is run server side, so if you're trying to pass a JS variable to a PHP array it's not going to work if the JS variable is calculated first. JS is always run client side. If you're new to web programming this is a simple, but very important concept :)

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is to output a JS array/object using PHP first.

```
var pu = <?php echo json_encode($pu) ?>
var mArray = <?php echo json_encode( $mArray ) ?>
```

Now run the JS loop etc.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    chart.addSeries({
        name: pu[i],
        data: mArray[i]
    })
}
```